# Why is the も particle used when asking to borrow something?

Tags: grammar, particle-も

If I ask, "Can I borrow a pencil?" I might say: エンピツを借りてもいいですか？

Why do we use the も particle here, since we're not saying **also** this or that? To express **also** is the main usage of mo I'm familiar with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course, 〜てもいい is not limited to borrowing, but rather any form of permission.

Being very literal...

> エンピツを借りる "to borrow a pencil"
>   エンピツを借りていい？ "Is it okay if I borrow a pencil?"
>   エンピツを借りて**も**いい？ "Is it okay **even** if I borrow a pencil?"

It is certainly not ungrammatical to have a も there (syntactically, you can insert any 係助詞{かかりじょし} between the て and the following verb/adjective), and semantically it makes sense as well.

The fact that the form with the も is more *popular*, however, is just idiomatic.

Comment: I was under the impression that -ていい was -てもいい with も dropped. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Sjiveru Historically, I think 〜てもいい is 〜ていい with も inserted. However, you are probably correct that these days it's the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so looked this up, and it looks like this is an idiomatic expression of sorts as it doesn't seem to strictly follow the typical usage of the も particle. Typically も does indicate "also" something.

Yet, something + もいいですか? seems to be the idiomatic way to say, "Can I do something"

Likewise, something + もいいです。 would be the way to say, "You can do something."

Correct me if I'm wrong to consider this somewhat of an idiomatic structure, and if there actually is a grammar rule that is being used here.

Reference: http://nihongo.anthonet.com/mo-ii-desu-wa-ikemasen/

Comment: It's mildly idiomatic, but really it's a pretty normal, if conventionalised, use of -ても. You could literally translate -てもいいですか as 'is it okay (even) if I...'.